# How to change the ssh port for a specific ip address?

Tags: ssh, ip, dedicated-server, putty

I get the trouble with putty, so I prefer using shell (linux) to access server via ssh, my ip address has alter port for ssh is 6091, so is there anyway to access server via ssh by command

```
ssh root@myipaddress
```

Because I have many server has default ssh port is 22, so I just want to change port to specific ip address.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The most comfortable solution in long-term is to add the host to your `~/.ssh/config` file. Edit/create the file and add:

```
 Host home
 User root
 Hostname myipaddress
 Port 6091
```

Then you can simply connect to home with:

```
 ssh home
```

More info

- http://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer as "correct" on serverfault.com if you think it is the best fit to your question :)

Answer (score 10):

ssh -p 6091 root@myipaddress

```
-p port
             Port to connect to on the remote host.  This can be specified on a per-host basis in the configuration file.
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your ~/.ssh/config

```
 Host special
    HostName special.myjob.com
    Port 22000
    User fooey
```

Now you can just run:

```
 ssh special
```

to get

```
 ssh -p 22000 fooey@special.myjob.com
```

More ssh tips at:

http://nerderati.com/2011/03/17/simplify-your-life-with-an-ssh-config-file/

Answer (score 0):

For a system wide change, you can change the port number in the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file and then restart the ssh service / deamon